# Is there any possible to save the output integer into array?

Tags: python, arrays, database, sqlite

everybody. I'm sorry if I look dumb at asking this question but I find this hard to complete my assignment.

```
profile = Databaseprofile.get_all_profile(connection)

for prof in profile:
    date = prof[2]
    datem = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    tod = datem.day
    mos = datem.month
    yr = datem.year
    today_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    dob = datetime.datetime(yr, mos, tod)
    time_diff = today_date - dob
    Age = time_diff.days
    #Databaseprofile.insertionsort(Age) 
    print(Age//365, end=' ')
```

My goal is that I want to get the Age output as an array and store it so that I can use it for the sorting algorithm. Is there any possible way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: If your aim is to create a simple array/list of ages. You can create a variable `age_list = []` before the `for loop` and use it inside like `age_list.append(Age)`.

Comment: oh i got it, i just put // 365 on Age variable

Comment: LOT OF THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `ages.append(Age // 365)` to collect all years into single list `ages`.

In following example I replaced `Databaseprofile.get_all_profile(connection)` with my own examples of dates, so that this example can be runnable easily by all StackOverflow users, without using any extra dependencies like database.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFba4MwFH7Przi0FBVMG9u1o4M9DPa89yEiaY1toLmQBIa/3uWotWObD@GcL9/lmGO7cDV61/dSWeMCNDyIIJUgZAnWmVbeBLzCOw/8xL2YkPVFhJrfbvXUp2ejtTgHaXRGHqqy/DBa5DCeooLWOBAgNZTJlhXPlB1pcUhyiB3bUvZE2R674nhklB0oK5KqIoRfhEe3WKIB@qPHlPNCIH44duQgVm6rGVIRu//Rei58cBaLFJEcFqtPulJ01SyyQRhMM8lU1HQDpoyfMWV0uA5o52awE9zd1byrp3n@ZmvzlY4xjTn9x0g7l2Ncjk7TQBGuG9m2kf/DnqLFQHi7YNhMw6n9cLH8vTipvXC4Jx@XnUZdBgMR33jNrRW6QRQ2G9gd9mO8dVKHFBklLaq4SI3vk0CSETLeZeTByfr@Gw)

```py
import datetime

# profile = Databaseprofile.get_all_profile(connection)
profile = [[None, None, e] for e in ['2017-09-16', '2002-04-05', '1990-06-01']]

ages = []

for prof in profile:
    date = prof[2]
    datem = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    tod = datem.day
    mos = datem.month
    yr = datem.year
    today_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    dob = datetime.datetime(yr, mos, tod)
    time_diff = today_date - dob
    Age = time_diff.days
    #Databaseprofile.insertionsort(Age) 
    ages.append(Age // 365)
    print(ages[-1], end = ' ')

print()
print(ages)
```

Output:

```
4 19 31
[4, 19, 31]
```